# Bring back the welcome screen in Sketch App

Tags: sketch-3

I need to bring back the welcome screen in Sketch App, seems that i uncheck "Show this window on launch" and can´t find a way to show it again.

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*bmLfDcvQwO4E60FcSWIqcA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the the Menu Window and select Welcome Window. Be sure to check "Show this widow on launch" to see it again every time.

[Menu Location Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCJqa.jpg)